# Same variable is showing different values

Tags: javascript

```js
var columnsDataList = {
  "checkbox": null,
  "status": "status3",
  "invoiceId": null,
  "invoiceDate": "invoiceDate6",
  "type": "type4"
};
console.log(columnsDataList);


var receivedOrderKey = [];
var receivedOrderKey = Object.keys(columnsDataList).map(function(key) {
  var checkNull = columnsDataList[key];
  if (checkNull != null) {
    receivedOrderKey.push(key);
    console.log(receivedOrderKey)
  }
});


console.log("it's coming blank here", receivedOrderKey);
```

`receivedOrderKey` is getting all the non - null values. But in the final `console.log` it's showing undefined for 5 elements. Where am I going wrong? I only want the key for which the values are not null.

Comment: `.map()` expects a return, without it everything in the array is being set to `undefined` or blank as you put it

Comment: @George why comment? write it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override `columnsDataList` when typing

```
var receivedOrderKey = Object.keys(columnsDataList)...
```

Keeping your logic, you can do that:

```
var receivedOrderKey = [];
Object.keys(columnsDataList).map(function (key) {
    var checkNull = columnsDataList[key];
    if(checkNull != null) { 
        receivedOrderKey.push(key);
    }
});
```

Or cleaner:

```
var receivedOrderKey = Object.keys(columnsDataList).filter(function(key) {
    return columnsDataList[key] !=null
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

remove `var receivedOrderKey =` in front of `Object.keys`

```js
var columnsDataList = {
  "checkbox": null,
  "status": "status3",
  "invoiceId": null,
  "invoiceDate": "invoiceDate6",
  "type": "type4"
};
console.log(columnsDataList);


var receivedOrderKey = [];
Object.keys(columnsDataList).map(function(key) {
  var checkNull = columnsDataList[key];
  if (checkNull != null) {
    receivedOrderKey.push(key);
    console.log(receivedOrderKey)
  }
});


console.log("it's coming here", receivedOrderKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
var columnsDataList = {"checkbox":null,"status":"status3","invoiceId":null,"invoiceDate":"invoiceDate6","type":"type4"};
    console.log(columnsDataList);


    var receivedOrderKey = [];
    Object.keys(columnsDataList).map(function (key) {
        var checkNull = columnsDataList[key];
        if(checkNull != null){ 
            receivedOrderKey.push(key);
        }
     });


   console.log("it's coming blank here",receivedOrderKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this I'd use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var columnsDataList = {
  "checkbox": null,
  "status": "status3",
  "invoiceId": null,
  "invoiceDate": "invoiceDate6",
  "type": "type4"
};

var receivedOrderKey =
  Object.keys(columnsDataList).filter(k => columnsDataList[k] != null);

console.log(receivedOrderKey)
```